# How to exclude original $0 in this awk script?

Tags: awk, cygwin

Using Cygwin64 here.

Here's an extract of my file. Notice the product_id is
not unique.

```
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW">LRZCQPLRQW</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW">LRZCQPLRQW</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to make the product_id unique by concatentating 
the rownumber after QW.

The following awk script does what I need, but it also prints the original row 
below the new row. If I exclude `{print $0}`, then I only get the **product_id** rows.

`awk '/LRZ/ {x=NR;  print substr($0,1,33) x substr($0,34,12) x substr($0,46);} {print $0}' my_file.html`

**CURRENT RESULTS**

```
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW">LRZCQPLRQW</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW">LRZCQPLRQW</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
```

**DESIRED RESULTS**

```
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` statement will keep awk from continuing to execute actions if you just want to move to the next line of input:

```
 $ awk '/LRZ/ {print substr($0,1,33) NR substr($0,34,12) NR substr($0,46); next} {print $0}' file
   <tr>
   <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
   <td>Crate</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
   <td>Crate</td>
   </tr>
```

Or if you prefer, you can simply negate the pattern for when you want to print the original line as is:

```
$ awk '/LRZ/ {print substr($0,1,33) NR substr($0,34,12) NR substr($0,46)}
      $0 !~ /LRZ/ {print $0}' file
   <tr>
   <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
   <td>Crate</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
   <td>Crate</td>
   </tr>
```

Often this would be written more idiomatically as:

```
$ awk '/LRZ/ {print substr($0,1,33) NR substr($0,34,12) NR substr($0,46); next}1' file
```

using the `next` statement and the always-true pattern `1` whose default action is to print the original line.

Comment: Or just `awk '/LRZ/{$0=substr($0,1,33) NR substr($0,34,12) NR substr($0,46)} 1' file`

Answer (score 4):

I've no idea why the answers so far are so complicated. Isn't this all you need?

```
$ awk '{gsub(/LRZ[^"<]+/,"&"NR)}1' file
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
    <td>Crate</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What about the _search after id?

Comment: It's a mistake in the question. The OP posted a script that she said does what she wants except for also printing the original line and that script does nothing related to adding "_search". She also selected as correct an answer that does nothing with "_search". So it must be present in the input or not be needed in the output - either way the script I posted will work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a `next` as the final command in your `LRZ` processing section, this will immediately move to the next line:

```
/LRZ/{x=NR;print substr($0,1,33) x substr($0,34,12) x substr($0,46);next}{print $0}
```

Comment: @Ed, that was in the original code. I didn't bother optimising that away since my answer was really just to add the `next` command to stop processing of the line after printing. I *could* have done that but then I probably would have had to redo the substrings as something more robust as well :-) In any case, your solution is much more elegant and gets rid of the kludgey substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Try following awk too once without hardcoding any place value here and simply by substituting the letters coming in "" and ><.

```
awk '/product_id/{sub(/\".[^"]*/,"&"NR);sub(/>.[^<]*/,"&"NR);} 1'  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Adding output as per OP's request here.

```
awk '/product_id/{sub(/\".[^"]*/,"&"NR);sub(/>.[^<]*/,"&"NR);} 1' Input_file
<tr>
<td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW2">LRZCQPLRQW2</td>
<td>Crate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td product_id="LRZCQPLRQW6">LRZCQPLRQW6</td>
<td>Crate</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected new line error message:

$ awk '/product_id/{sub(/\".[^"]*/,"&"NR);sub(/>.[^<]*/,"&"NR); 1'  input_file

awk: cmd. line:1: /product_id/{sub(/\".[^"]*/,"&"NR);sub(/>.[^<]*/,"&"NR); 1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                           ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: @zundarz: Which Os you are using here? As it is working fine for me, see my update where I am getting the exact output, let me know on same.,

Comment: I'm using Cygwin64 on a Win7-64 bit OS.

Comment: Ravinder, I copied this to a Linux server and got results with out errors. Thanks for sharing. This works on Linux.

Comment: The reported error had nothing to do with awk version or OS, the OP copy/pasted incorrectly or made some other mistake. The script will work in any awk on any UNIX system.